# How can I run multiple rdl (not rdlc) reports through Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: reporting-services

I have several SSRS reports (RDL) created in SQL Server 2014. I want to run these multiple RDLs through Visual Studio 2015.

I am able to run one RDL through VS2015 by giving the server name and report path in the report viewer as shown in this [ReportViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI18H.png) image.

But I am not able to run multiple RDLs. Can someone help me out in this project?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089.aspx

```
    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;  

    LocalReport localReport = reportViewer1.LocalReport;  

    localReport.ReportPath = "Sales Order Detail.rdl";
```

Comment: Can I run multiple RDL reports through one report viewer with the above code?